# how can i synchronize the django celery task?

Tags: django, task, celery

I have two celery task

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def task1():

@app.task(bind=True)
def task2():
```

and each task is called by a different api like following

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def api1(request):
    task_1.delay()

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def api2(request):
    task_2.delay()
```

if task2 is called when task1 is running in the background,
I want to run task2 after task1 is finished

how can i solved the problem??

I'm also considering giving one queue for each user

Please give me a perfect solution...

Comment: What are your tasks doing that requires them to be synchronous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem consists of two subproblems:

1. Ensure that `task2` doesn't start when `task1` is running. You can solve this by implementing a distributed lock, e.g. [using Redis.](https://redis.io/topics/distlock)
2. Ensure that `task2` does start once `task1` has finished. This can be solved by [re-trying](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#retrying) `task2` until the lock becomes available.

Here is some pseudo-code:

```
def task1():
    with distributed_lock():
        # do actual task

def task2():
    while not is_lock_available():
         self.retry()
    # do actual task
```

There are a couple of details to consider:

- what happens if `task1` is triggered when `task1` is already running?
- what happens if `task2` is triggered when `task2` is already running?
- what kind of delay is acceptable before a waiting `task2` job is started?
- what happens if another `task1` job is scheduled between `task1` finishing and a waiting `task2` job starting?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. there are many things to consider and it seems to be a dangerous way to do. so I should either eliminate the dependency between the two tasks or make them one task